# How to save multiple xml files in cache file path in ios?

Tags: ios, xml, download

Im saving xml file in cache file path as follows:

```
// Determile cache file path
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 filePathl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"list.xml"];   

// Download and write to file
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:detail_product_listing_rss];
 NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 [urlData writeToFile:filePathl atomically:YES];
```

But using this code i can retrive data of recently used xml file.Could anybody please tell me how to save multiple xml files for offline use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the xml with different names. Else it'll overwrite old xml.

Keep a integer value for this purpose, if you want this after the app restart also keep it in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
 int posValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastXml"] intValue];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 filePathl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/list_%d.xml", [paths objectAtIndex:0],posValue];   

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:detail_product_listing_rss];
 NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 [urlData writeToFile:filePathl atomically:YES];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:posValue+1] forKey:@"lastXml"];
```

Comment: could you tell me how to retrieve this file using NSURLConnection?

Comment: This file is stored in document directory, then why are you using NSURLConnection for retrieving it ?

Comment: If you want to know how to read file from document directory check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038228/how-to-read-a-file-from-documents-directory